# How to send string to third-party APP in Android

Tags: android

Experts,

For example, a third-party APP has text boxes for user to input username/password/etc.

I would like to develop a APP to fill in the username/password to replace manual input.

How to achieve this?

Mainly I would like to know what information need from the third-party APP and how to get them, then how to communicate the information with my APP.

For example, in winform, I need the handle of the text box from the third-party APP, and I get it(handle) by spy++:

1. base on main window title to get the main handle.
2. base on main handle to find the child handle from the specify layer.

But I have no idea how to do in Android. Also, if it is doable, how to do it in background, so it won't bother me while I am watching a movie in the phone.

Note that the target is not third-party APP, but a widget in a activity belongs to third-party APP.

Many thanks.

Comment: look into broadcasting Intents

Comment: This may be possible (I would suspect it would be VERY difficult, because every receiving app needs a method to pull the information that your app pushes), but there would be security flaws for it to work in the background. Your phone could essentially hack itself, a person could log into every account you've ever created with those credentials, etc. This is why Google introduced the one-click Google sign in. I see some cool uses of what you're dreaming up, I'm just pointing out that it may be a hard one. Good luck!

Comment: If the "hack itself" idea from above doesn't make sense, I would point out that computer programs are set up in a way that information is only accessible [access modifiers, etc] where it needs to be. If login information is accessible with a simple method call, any other program is rendered insecure.. That's no bueno. :) If you've seen the 'Captcha' checkboxes, this is what that's for. On Android, a button has to be pressed. I hope my logic is making sense. I'm trying to throw out some possible hurdles, not dissuade you from your idea.

Comment: Sorry don't understand the logic of hack. If third-party APP has a text box or button, then it allowed to input and click, and I just want to input and click using my App instead of my fingers, totally not hack related. I still walk in the room through the door, not the window.